# Azure DevOps Pipeline - list all Build SourceBranches

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

This is my simple pipeline,

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

pool:
  name: LinuxJavaCIBuildAgents #CheckmarxAgents #LinuxJavaCIBuildAgents

workspace:
  clean: all

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repo_a
    type: git
    name: InternalProjects/repo_a
    trigger:
      - main
      - release

  - repository: repo_b
    type: git
    name: InternalProjects/repo_b
    trigger:
      - main
      - release

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: echo ....??? what to echo to list all repositories and their source branch from resources.repositories
```

How do I list all Build SourceBranches that are involved in the above build pipeline? we have 2 repos: repo_a and repo_b, I want to list them using bash and list their source branches.

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify why you need to list the source branches? When a pipeline runs, it's context is for specific branch.

Comment: I want to be sure that all repositories run on the same branch during the build, otherwise, if someone set the resource to a repo_b to be built on develop branch while repo_a is on the master branch, the pipeline should know about this change and set the specific variable so that I could use it later on for some other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I list all Build SourceBranches that are involved in the above
> build pipeline? we have 2 repos: repo_a and repo_b, I want to list
> them using bash and list their source branches.

Azure DevOps supports multiple repositories check out as a built-in function, Refer to the YAML code below:-

```bash
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml
pool:
vmImage: ubuntu-latest
workspace:
clean: all
resources:
repositories:
- repository: repo_a
type: git
name: InternalProjects/repo_a
ref: main
trigger:
- main
- release
- repository: repo_b
type: git
name: InternalProjects/repo_b
ref: main
trigger:
- main
- release
steps:
- checkout: repo_a
- checkout: repo_b
- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

While running the pipeline it will ask for authorization to allow both the repositories to run like below:-

[image]

After granting the permission:-

[image]

To list the  **build source branches**  of the above repos you can use the below echo command as a Bash Inline script in your YAML code:-

```bash
# Starter pipeline

# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.

# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:

# https://aka.ms/yaml
pool:
vmImage: ubuntu-latest
workspace:
clean: all
resources:
repositories:
- repository: repo_a
type: git
name: InternalProjects/repo_a
trigger:
- main
- release
- repository: repo_b
type: git
name: InternalProjects/repo_b
trigger:
- main
- release
steps:
- task: Bash@3
inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: |
#!/bin/bash
echo
for repo in $(echo $(echo "${resources}" | jq -r '.repositories[].name')); do
echo "Repository: $repo"
echo "Source branches: $(echo "${resources}" | jq -r '.repositories[] | select(.name == "$repo") | .trigger[]')"
echo "Source branches"
done
```

Pipeline Run:-

[image]

If you want to make sure  **all repos run on the same branch and require a warning if another repo runs on a different branch,**  Use below YAML code:-

```yaml
# Starter pipeline

# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.

# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:

# https://aka.ms/yaml

  

pool:

vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  

workspace:

clean: all

  

resources:

repositories:

- repository: repo_a

type: git

name: InternalProjects/repo_a

trigger:

- main

- release

  

- repository: repo_b

type: git

name: InternalProjects/repo_b

trigger:

- main

steps:

- task: Bash@3

inputs:

targetType: 'inline'

script: |

#!/bin/bash

# Get the source branch of the first repository

source_branch=$(echo "${resources}" | jq -r '.repositories[0].trigger[]')

# Loop through the other repositories and compare the source branch with the first repository

for repo in $(echo $(echo "${resources}" | jq -r '.repositories[].name' | tail -n +2)); do

if [[ $(echo "${resources}" | jq -r '.repositories[] | select(.name == "$repo") | .trigger[]') != "$source_branch" ]]; then

echo "Error: Repository $repo is running on a different branch ($(echo "${resources}" | jq -r '.repositories[] | select(.name == "$repo") | .trigger[]')) than the first repository ($source_branch)"

exit 1

fi

done

echo "All repositories are set to run on branch $source_branch"
```

Output:-

[image]

**Reference :-**

[Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops)